# Why is Nisekoi's name written in Katakana?

Tags: nisekoi

Noticed it first in this Jump cover in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Katakana is used for spelling out foreign words. Nisekoi is Japanese for "fake love". So, why is katakana used? Just to make the name seem more "cool"?

Comment: My .02 would be marketing? I learned in my Japanese class that in most business cases like product marketing when dealing with titles of products either katakana or kanji is used.

Comment: There's a greater chance for non-Japanese to be able to read Katakana compared to reading kanji. Other than that it is just styling. Just like fripSide was styled as such and not Fripside, ClariS and not Claris, sweetARMS not Sweet Arms. Note that in Japanese there is no capital letter, thus they stylize by using Katakana instead.

Comment: @AyaseEri I don’t think manga magazines will think of non-Japanese in any way … Japan *is* their main market …

Comment: The one to give the title is the author, not the magazine.

Comment: Replace *magazine* with *author* and nothing in the argument changes.